# Listen /Unlisten to events Java

Tags: java, android

Okay, how I would do it in C#

```
android.view.MotionEvent-=surfaceTouchEvent;
android.view.MotionEvent += waitForStart;
```

My question is: How to do that with Java (I am doing this inside Processing's IDE, so auto-anything)

Thanks for your help and understanding!

Florian R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't have delegates. What you are expected to use is listeners. Not sure what your exact class names will be since you seem to be using some .Net libraries, but it should look something along the lines:

```
view.addMotionEventListener(new MotionEventListener(){

     @Override
     public void onMotionEvent(View v, EventArgs e){
            //Your event code here.
     }
});
```

Look into the android documentation and basic Java programming before you get involved with any Android development.